# How Do I retrieve values from an appended placeholder with ID?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, append, placeholder

So I made a button that creates an input placeholder every time it is clicked (limited to 4).  The problem is, I am using post method, and doing .value in my code returns a TypeError, but not the default placeholders (eg: m1k1).  The IDs are created, and they're similar to the default with the exception of a number that is generated in a for loop.

When I type in values in just the default placeholders, everything is fine.

Two elements

```
let m1k1 = document.querySelector('#mon1wk1')
let m1k2 = document.querySelector('#mon1wk2')
```

eventListener

```
let num = 1
function addWeek(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    num++

    let mkInput = document.createElement('input')
    let forma = document.querySelector('#forma')
    mkInput.placeholder = " "
    mkInput.id = 'mon1wk' + num
    mkInput.type = 'text'
    forma.append(mkInput)
        if (num === 4) {
            addwk1.disabled = true;
```

Where values get stored into an object

```
    pushMonths.firstMonth.Week1 = m1k1.value,
    pushMonths.firstMonth.Week2 = m1k2.value,
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is a default placeholder? *"...my code returns a TypeError, but not the default placeholders (eg: m1k1)"* What returns a TypeError? The event handler is incomplete.

Comment: What I mean is a placeholder that's already in the code, one that isn't created from clicking the button.

Also, if it helps, when I use console in devtools, typing m1k1 returns 'input#mon1wk1' but m1k2 returns 'null'

Comment: Nevermind, solved it.  I just changed m1k2 to ID (mon1wk2)

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180722/2813224) automatically assigns ids and object properties accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP code the `num` equals 1, so when the id is assigned to a new `<input>` when the user clicks the `<button>`, the first `<input>` is assigned `id="mon1wk1"` and the second `<input>` is assigned `id="mon1wk2"`. So now there's 2 pairs of `<input>` sharing the same `id` which is invalid plus the duplicates cannot be found by `id` since the browser quits searching as soon as it finds the first `id`, which explains why the static `<input>`s always worked.

In the example below, the object follows the following pattern:

**Figure I**

```
const obj = {
  mw: [2, 1], // [2nd month, 1st week]
  mon1: {     // Each mon* object can have up to 4 wk* properties
    wk1: mon1wk1.value,
      ⇓⇓⇓
    wk4: mon1wk4.value
  },
  mon2: {
    wk1: mon2wk1.value
  }
};
```

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference <form>
const frm = document.forms.forma;
/**
 * @param {object} obj - Used to keep data
 * @param {array} obj.mw - Keeps count of current
 *        month at mw[0] and week at mw[1]
 * @param {object} obj.mon* - Month holds 4 weeks
 * @param {any} obj.wk* - Week holds associated
 *        <input> value
 */
const obj = {
  mw: [1, 2],
  mon1: {
    wk1: 5,
    wk2: 4
  }
};
let m = obj.mw[0];
let w = obj.mw[1];

// Bind submit event to <form>
frm.onsubmit = addWeek;

function addWeek(e) {
  // Stop <form> from killing page
  e.preventDefault();
  // Build new <input>
  let mk = document.createElement('input');
  mk.type = 'text';
  frm.append(mk);
  /*
  Incerment 'w' 
  If 'w' is greater than 4...
  ...add a new 'mon*' object and assign it a new
  'w'
  *//*
  Otherwise assign a new property to current 'mon*'
  Assign id to new <input> with this pattern:
  `mon${m}wk${w}`
  */
  ++w;
  if (w > 4) {
    ++m;
    w = 1;
    obj['mon' + m] = {
      ['wk' + w]: 0
    };
    obj.mw[0] = m;
    obj.mw[1] = 1;
  } else {
    obj['mon' + m]['wk' + w] = 0;
    obj.mw[1] += 1;
  }
  mk.id = 'mon' + m + 'wk' + w;
  console.log(obj);
}

// Bind input event to <form>
frm.oninput = saveData;
/*
When a user inputs a value into an <input>, assign
the value to the associated property of obj.
The value is coerced into a number: +mk.value
Remove the '+' if you want string instead.
*/
function saveData(e) {
  const mk = e.target;
  let id = mk.id;
  obj[id.slice(0, 4)][id.slice(4)] = +mk.value;
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

button,
input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id='forma'>
  <button id='addWk'>Add Week</button><br><hr>
  <input id='mon1wk1' value='5'>
  <input id='mon1wk2' value='4'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I’m gonna look through this, understand it, and see if I could tweak this or my code.  I appreciate your help and effort!